# Error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] while trying to delete file from directory

Tags: python, operating-system, win32com

I'm trying to delete a specific file from a directory with the following code:

```
def PPTtoPDF(inputFileName = 'presentation.pptx', outputFileName = 'presentation.pdf', formatType = 32):
    try: 
        os.remove(os.path.abspath(outputFileName))
    except:
        pass
    powerpoint = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    powerpoint.Visible = 1
    if outputFileName[-3:] != 'pdf':
        outputFileName = outputFileName + ".pdf"
    deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(os.path.abspath(inputFileName))
    deck.SaveAs(outputFileName, formatType) # formatType = 32 for ppt to pdf
    deck.Close()
    powerpoint.Quit()

    return os.path.abspath(outputFileName)
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-c809253c599e> in <module>
----> 1 pdf_file = PPTtoPDF()

~\Documents\ppt.py in PPTtoPDF(inputFileName, outputFileName, formatType)
    129     try:
--> 130         os.remove(os.path.abspath(outputFileName))
    131     except:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\...\\presentation.pdf'
```

Any help will be very apreciated

Comment: It seems that you do not expect `outputFileName`to have the .pdf ending (see lines 8+9), so you add it. With `os.remove` you dont do that though. So I would guess its probably because of that. What does you `outputFileName` string print when called?

Comment: Although it has this 2 lines of code, I'm putting a `pdf` extension on it. When  I try to run the code (`pdf_file = PPTtoPDF()`), the powerpoint does open and shows a 'Publishing' window, then it closes and the following error pops-up:  `COMError: (-2147188160, None, ('Application (unknown member) : Invalid request.  This operation cannot be performed in this event handler.', 'Microsoft PowerPoint', '', 0, None)) `. And when I try to call this pdf_file var, it says that it isn't defined. Any thought?